# how to open bootstrap modal from other blade file ? (laravel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

1.this is present in file index.blade.php .In this between html code one button tag is placed in which data target is present in different file .Can it be possible to trigger the modal from remote button

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-warning btn-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".ept-modal" onclick="productTestMapModal('<?=base64_encode(base64_encode($product->id));?>')">Available Tests</button>
```

2.while modal target file is

```
<div class="clear-back">
<div class="modal-header">
    {{ $product->name }} - Available tests
    <button type="button" title="Close" class="close pull-right white" data-dismiss="modal">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="pad-15">
    <span class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-circle user-online"></i> Select tests to be mapped in {{ $product->name }}</span>
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-circle" onclick="productTestMap(this, '<?=base64_encode(base64_encode($product->id));?>')">Save</button>
    
    <div class="clearfix"></div><br/>
    

    <div style="width:99%;overflow-y:auto;">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="center">
                    @foreach($product->course->testGroups as $testgroup)
                        <th>{{ $testgroup->name }}   
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm" onclick="selectTestgroups('{{$testgroup->id}}')">Select All</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm" onclick="unselectTestgroups('{{$testgroup->id}}')">UnSelect All</button>
                        </th>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    @foreach($product->course->testGroups as $testgroup)
                        <td>
                            @foreach($testgroup->subgroups as $subgroup)
                                @foreach($subgroup->tests as $t)
                                    <span class="badge badgetest_{{$testgroup->id}} {{ in_array($t->id,$product_tests) ? 'selected' : '' }}" onclick="toggleSelection(this)"><span class="test-id hidden">{{ $t->id }}</span>{{ $t->name }}</span>
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
                        </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you @include both files, in the parent blade file, because "In two different files" makes no difference. It all gets rendered into one big html file. Your browser has no idea, and no concern how it was built.

Answer (score 0):

in order to open modal from another blade file, you have to include that file, button in the target file index.blade.php like so:
`@include('rel_path_to_modal_file.modal_file_name')`

and please follow the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/) to use modal as it call by id, not a class.